# Problem when trying to wrap chains of width-constrained views

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout, beta

I'm trying to implement a very common portrait/landscape layout flexibility approach using newly-introduced ConstraintLayout Flow helper in chain wrapping mode.

I want to position two views automatically in line for landscape orientation and one under another for portrait, e.g. wrap to fit. I can achieve this already with FlexboxLayout but I prefer a flat structure and performance of ConstraintLayout.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B0B0B0">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1,view2"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:background="#808080"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
    </View>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
    </View>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I get this for landscape, and it's fine:

[image: landscape]

But I get this for portrait:

[image: portrait, unexpected]

If I set fixed width 200dp (or wrap_content for other cases also ok), everything works as expected:

[image: portrait, expected]

Since ConstraintLayout 2.0.0 is in beta and recent changelog reports about fixes in wrap support, I suppose that it is a bug.

But maybe I'm missing something? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The default orientation of the `Flow` widget is horizontal. Therefore, it needs to know `layout_width` values of its referenced widgets.

It seems that `Flow` can't calculate these values based on the `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` (at least, not in the Tools preview.. I did not test how it behaves at runtime).

In your code, you can swap the `layout_width` and `layout_height` values to achieve your desired results.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_red, view_blue"
        app:flow_wrapMode="chain"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_red"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#C62828"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_blue"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#1565C0"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, keep in mind that chaining/wrapping only occurs if the referenced widgets do not fit in the specified orientation (default: horizontal). In my code, I had to set `layout_width` to 300dp for chaining to happen in the Tools preview.

So, if you're running on a tablet, for example, using this method will not guarantee that your widgets will be positioned vertically because there is more horizontal space to accommodate the widgets.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Actually, my real case is much complex than this layout: more views/constraints, etc. Here I tried to simplify everything as much as possible to reveal the problem, that's why some values were hardcoded. And the main goal is to obtain the correct view placements without changing code/properties, e.g. flow orientations.

Comment: No problem, it's a good question, and it was the first time I heard of Flow. It seems like a good feature that will come in handy. But, I think if you want to guarantee that you widgets are stacked vertically in portrait mode, you should consider going with dedicated layout files for portrait/landscape. It would be nice if they added an attribute like `flow_maxWidthWrap` (similar to `flow_maxElementsWrap`) that triggers the chain if the elements reach a specified width/percentage of the screen.